# Replace remaining values in a data frame row with NA based on the first occurrence of a vale in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, mapply

I have two data frames, one of which has a subset of rows that are numeric and represent a time series, the other of which is a data frame of 1's and 0's relating to the time points in the initial data frame.

Based on the boolean dataframe I would like to replace the values in the initial dataframe with NA's at the timepoint of the first occurrence of a 0 in the boolean dataframe.

An example is shown below:

```
df1

ID  category  t1   t2   t3
1      A      5    5.2  7
2      A      7    7.5  8
3      B      9    10.3 11
4      B      3    4.1  4.7
5      C      2    3    4.5


df2

t1   t2   t3
0     1   1
1     0   1
1     1   1
1     1   0
0     0   1
```

The resulting dataframe should just be a modified version of the first but with certain values replaced by NA based on df2 as shown below

```
df1

ID  category  t1   t2   t3
1      A      NA   NA   NA
2      A      7    NA   NA
3      B      9    10.3 11
4      B      3    4.1  NA
5      C      NA   NA   NA
```

I'm struggling to find what would be a very efficient way to do this in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option with `rowCumsums`.  Create a logical `matrix` from 'df2' (`df2 == 0`), then use `rowCumsums` to get the cumulative sum by each row, change it to logical matrix ( `> 0`) and replace those corresponding elements in 'df1' to `NA`

```
library(matrixStats)
df1[names(df2)] <- df1[names(df2)] *NA^(rowCumsums(df2 == 0) > 0)
```

which can be also written as

```
df1[names(df2)][rowCumsums(df2 == 0) > 0] <- NA
```

-output

```
df1
#  ID category t1   t2 t3
#1  1        A NA   NA NA
#2  2        A  7   NA NA
#3  3        B  9 10.3 11
#4  4        B  3  4.1 NA
#5  5        C NA   NA NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, category = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"
), t1 = c(5L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 2L), t2 = c(5.2, 7.5, 10.3, 4.1, 3), 
    t3 = c(7, 8, 11, 4.7, 4.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(t1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), t2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L), t3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```